# What is wrong with my logic for the question CountNonDivisible in Codility?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to solve the question of CountNonDivisible on Codility and below is my solution. I am getting only a 55% overall score. My logic was that I would count all the divisors of an element present in the array and subtract them from the total length of the array to obtain the number of non-divisors for each element.

This question is from the lessons section of Codility and can be viewed in this link under Lesson 11:
[CountNonDvisible](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/11-sieve_of_eratosthenes/)

```
import math
def solution(A):
    B = reversed(sorted(A))
    d = dict()
    n = len(A)
    res = dict()
    for i in A:
        if i not in d:
            d[i] = 1
            continue
        d[i]+= 1
    for i in B:
        tmp = 0
        if i == 1:
            res[i] = n-d[i]
            continue
        if i==2 or i==3:
            res[i] = n-d[i]-d.get(1,0)
            continue
        for j in range(2,int(math.sqrt(i)+1)):
            if j in d and i%j == 0:
                if j == i//j:
                    tmp+=d[j]
                else:
                    tmp+=d[j]+d.get(i//j,0)
        if d[i]>1:
            res[i] = n-tmp-d.get(1,0)-d.get(i)
        else:
            res[i] = n-tmp-d.get(1,0)-1
    ans = []
    for i in A:
        ans.append(res[i])
    return ans
```

Comment: What exactly does the code do differently than you expect? Please show a [mre].

Comment: Well, it is failing 1 correctness test and 3 performance tests in Codility, but since the test cases are hidden I am unable to find the flaw in my logic. Unfortunately for the same reason, there is no reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's write a simple function that solves the problem correctly, if perhaps inefficiently:

```
def basic_sol(B):
  return [ len([d for d in B if b % d != 0]) for b in B ]
```

Then let's run a test to find out if we can find some error cases:

```
TRIALS=100
LENGTH=2
MAX_NUM=100
for trial in range(TRIALS):
  B = [ random.randint(1, MAX_NUM) for j in range(LENGTH) ]

  my_sol = solution(B)
  correct_sol = basic_sol(B)

  if(my_sol != correct_sol):
    print(B)
    print(my_sol)
    print(correct_sol)
    break
```

This produces some results pretty quickly:

```
Problem [63, 21]
My solution [1, 1]
Correct solution [0, 1]
```

Since 63 is divisible both by itself and by 21, the number of items in the list not dividing it should be zero, but your program returns 1.

Now your job is to take this test case, run it through your program, and figure out why it's being mishandled.

---

Separately, ask yourself exactly how much more efficient your solution is than the one-line solution given.  It seems like both are O(n^2).  Perhaps there is a more efficient way to handle things here?

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it this way

Comment: First thing I checked on codibility is the dummy solution (O(n^2)) and it also gets 55%. I think the point is to use the Sieve of Erathostene in some way to get a more efficient algorithm.